# Make gulp sync php files

Tags: php, gulp, localhost, gulp-connect

I want make gulp work with php files, so I search and see that I need gulp-connect-php plugin. After install it, I have tried a lot of possibilities but no success. My last code is below.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');    

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    // server: {
    //   baseDir: 'app'
    // },
    proxy: 'http://localhost/'
  })
})

gulp.task('connect', function() {
   connect.server({
      hostname: 'localhost',
      port: 8000,
      base: ''
   });
});
```

Comment: Your code is not like the documentation.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php and use their simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reply.
I solve that by changing code just like below:

```
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
});

gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
    });
  });

  gulp.watch('**/*.php').on('change', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
});
```

I also changed the httpd.conf file in the wamp64 folder just like [this](https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28) article